# Android Retrofit: How to display json data to a recyclerview in Android?

Tags: java, json, android-recyclerview

I have a problem on how to display my json data to a recycler view. Here is my JSON data in which I want to display both the "Player" and "Coach" object values in a single recycler view. I already work with some other json structure but this one is kind of complicated to me so I don't know how will I do it.

```
       {"success":1,"result":[{"team_key":"2616","team_name":"Chelsea","team_logo":"https:\/\/allsportsapi.com\/logo\/2616_chelsea.png","players":[{"player_key":3440253915,"player_name":"Arrizabalaga Kepa","player_number":"1","player_country":"Spain","player_type":"Goalkeepers","player_age":"26","player_match_played":"3","player_goals":"0","player_yellow_cards":"0","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":2059460065,"player_name":"Caballero Wilfredo","player_number":"13","player_country":"Argentina","player_type":"Goalkeepers","player_age":"39","player_match_played":"1","player_goals":"0","player_yellow_cards":"0","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":2488764308,"player_name":"Mendy Edouard","player_number":"16","player_country":"Senegal","player_type":"Goalkeepers","player_age":"28","player_match_played":"12","player_goals":"0","player_yellow_cards":"0","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":3214711283,"player_name":"Alonso Marcos","player_number":"3","player_country":"Spain","player_type":"Defenders","player_age":"30","player_match_played":"3","player_goals":"0","player_yellow_cards":"1","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":749545136,"player_name":"Azpilicueta Cesar","player_number":"28","player_country":"Spain","player_type":"Defenders","player_age":"31","player_match_played":"7","player_goals":"0","player_yellow_cards":"2","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":2242127097,"player_name":"Chilwell Benjamin","player_number":"21","player_country":"England","player_type":"Defenders","player_age":"24","player_match_played":"13","player_goals":"2","player_yellow_cards":"1","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":2456000699,"player_name":"Christensen Andreas","player_number":"4","player_country":"Denmark","player_type":"Defenders","player_age":"24","player_match_played":"5","player_goals":"0","player_yellow_cards":"1","player_red_cards":"1"},{"player_key":2294955514,"player_name":"Emerson","player_number":"33","player_country":"Italy","player_type":"Defenders","player_age":"26","player_match_played":"2","player_goals":"0","player_yellow_cards":"0","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":3619559992,"player_name":"James Reece","player_number":"24","player_country":"England","player_type":"Defenders","player_age":"21","player_match_played":"13","player_goals":"1","player_yellow_cards":"3","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":2991724348,"player_name":"Rudiger Antonio","player_number":"2","player_country":"Germany","player_type":"Defenders","player_age":"27","player_match_played":"2","player_goals":"0","player_yellow_cards":"0","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":3356512369,"player_name":"Silva Thiago","player_number":"6","player_country":"Brazil","player_type":"Defenders","player_age":"36","player_match_played":"11","player_goals":"2","player_yellow_cards":"2","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":452013637,"player_name":"Tomori Fikayo","player_number":"14","player_country":"England","player_type":"Defenders","player_age":"23","player_match_played":"1","player_goals":"0","player_yellow_cards":"0","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":1529403595,"player_name":"Zouma Kurt","player_number":"15","player_country":"France","player_type":"Defenders","player_age":"26","player_match_played":"14","player_goals":"4","player_yellow_cards":"1","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":3998708501,"player_name":"Gilmour Billy","player_number":"23","player_country":"Scotland","player_type":"Midfielders","player_age":"19","player_match_played":"1","player_goals":"0","player_yellow_cards":"0","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":3868193151,"player_name":"Jorginho","player_number":"5","player_country":"Italy","player_type":"Midfielders","player_age":"29","player_match_played":"10","player_goals":"3","player_yellow_cards":"0","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":717905378,"player_name":"Kante N'Golo","player_number":"7","player_country":"France","player_type":"Midfielders","player_age":"29","player_match_played":"16","player_goals":"0","player_yellow_cards":"4","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":3915727687,"player_name":"Kovacic Mateo","player_number":"17","player_country":"Croatia","player_type":"Midfielders","player_age":"26","player_match_played":"11","player_goals":"0","player_yellow_cards":"0","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":1466702728,"player_name":"Mount Mason","player_number":"19","player_country":"England","player_type":"Midfielders","player_age":"21","player_match_played":"15","player_goals":"1","player_yellow_cards":"2","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":1747265972,"player_name":"Pulisic Christian","player_number":"10","player_country":"USA","player_type":"Midfielders","player_age":"22","player_match_played":"9","player_goals":"1","player_yellow_cards":"0","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":3026064276,"player_name":"Ziyech Hakim","player_number":"22","player_country":"Morocco","player_type":"Midfielders","player_age":"27","player_match_played":"7","player_goals":"1","player_yellow_cards":"1","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":2712092737,"player_name":"Abraham Tammy","player_number":"9","player_country":"England","player_type":"Forwards","player_age":"23","player_match_played":"14","player_goals":"6","player_yellow_cards":"0","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":3085557745,"player_name":"Giroud Olivier","player_number":"18","player_country":"France","player_type":"Forwards","player_age":"34","player_match_played":"9","player_goals":"3","player_yellow_cards":"1","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":1087701594,"player_name":"Havertz Kai","player_number":"29","player_country":"Germany","player_type":"Forwards","player_age":"21","player_match_played":"14","player_goals":"1","player_yellow_cards":"1","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":2773006276,"player_name":"Hudson-Odoi Callum","player_number":"20","player_country":"England","player_type":"Forwards","player_age":"20","player_match_played":"7","player_goals":"1","player_yellow_cards":"0","player_red_cards":"0"},{"player_key":640779808,"player_name":"Werner Timo","player_number":"11","player_country":"Germany","player_type":"Forwards","player_age":"24","player_match_played":"16","player_goals":"4","player_yellow_cards":"0","player_red_cards":"0"}],"coaches":[{"coach_name":"Lampard Frank","coach_country":"England","coach_age":"42"}]}]}
```

```
Mainactivity

    enter code herepackage com.example.teams.activity;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.teams.R;
import com.example.teams.adapter.TeamsAdapter;
import com.example.teams.model.Player;
import com.example.teams.model.Result;
import com.example.teams.model.TeamsMain;
import com.example.teams.rest.Api;
import com.example.teams.rest.ApiClient;
import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final static String TAG=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static final String API_key ="c3d5fc8869402cf4bb4b5e162b3c3aea30e4bb53f90607d3e621e9f6a250e30e";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        Api api= ApiClient.getClient().create(Api.class);

        Call<TeamsMain> call=api.getResult(API_key);
        
        call.enqueue(new Callback<TeamsMain>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TeamsMain> call, Response<TeamsMain> response) {
              if(!response.isSuccessful()){

                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error"+response.errorBody(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   return;
               }
                List<Result> resultList=response.body().getResult();


                recyclerView.setAdapter(new TeamsAdapter(resultList,R.layout.teams,getApplicationContext()));
                Log.d(TAG,"DATA"+resultList.size());

               Log.e("MainActivity","response"+response.body().toString());

               Log.d(TAG, "message received men");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TeamsMain> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("problem",t.toString());
            }
        });

    }
}


TEAMSADAPTER

    enter code herepackage com.example.teams.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TeamsMain {

    @SerializedName("success")
    private Integer success;
    @SerializedName("result")
    private List<Result> result ;
    public TeamsMain(Integer success, List<Result> result) {
        this.success = success;
        this.result = result;
    }



    public Integer getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Integer success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public List<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}

MODEL CLASSES
1. RESULTS

    package com.example.teams.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Result {

    @SerializedName("team_key")
    private String teamKey;
    @SerializedName("team_name")
    private String teamName;
    @SerializedName("team_logo")
    private String teamLogo;
    @SerializedName("players")

    private Player players;
    @SerializedName("coaches")

    private List<Coach>Coaches=new ArrayList<Coach>();


    public Result(String teamKey, String teamName, String teamLogo, Player players, List<Coach> coaches) {
        this.teamKey = teamKey;
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.teamLogo = teamLogo;
        this.players = players;
        this.Coaches = coaches;
    }

    public String getTeamKey() {
        return teamKey;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public String getTeamLogo() {
        return teamLogo;
    }

    public Player getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    public List<Coach> getCoaches() {
        return Coaches;
    }

    public void setTeamKey(String teamKey) {
        this.teamKey = teamKey;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamLogo(String teamLogo) {
        this.teamLogo = teamLogo;
    }

    public void setPlayers(Player players) {
        this.players = players;
    }

    public void setCoaches(List<Coach> coaches) {
        Coaches = coaches;
    }
}


2. COACH

    package com.example.teams.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Coach {

    @SerializedName("coach_name")

    private String coachName;
    @SerializedName("coach_country")

    private String coachCountry;
    @SerializedName("coach_age")

    private String coachAge;
    public Coach(String coachName, String coachCountry, String coachAge) {
        this.coachName = coachName;
        this.coachCountry = coachCountry;
        this.coachAge = coachAge;
    }


    public String getCoachName() {
        return coachName;
    }

    public void setCoachName(String coachName) {
        this.coachName = coachName;
    }

    public String getCoachCountry() {
        return coachCountry;
    }

    public void setCoachCountry(String coachCountry) {
        this.coachCountry = coachCountry;
    }

    public String getCoachAge() {
        return coachAge;
    }

    public void setCoachAge(String coachAge) {
        this.coachAge = coachAge;
    }

}

3. PLAYER

    package com.example.teams.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Player {

    @SerializedName("player_key")

    private long playerKey;
    @SerializedName("player_name")
    private String playerName;
    @SerializedName("player_number")
    private String playerNumber;
    @SerializedName("player_country")

    private String playerCountry;
    @SerializedName("player_type")

    private String playerType;
    @SerializedName("player_age")

    private String playerAge;
    @SerializedName("player_match_played")

    private String playerMatchPlayed;
    @SerializedName("player_goals")

    private String playerGoals;
    @SerializedName("player_yellow_cards")

    private String playerYellowCards;
    @SerializedName("player_Red_cards")

    private String playerRedCards;

    public Player(Integer playerKey, String playerName, String
            playerNumber, String playerCountry, String playerType, String
            playerAge, String playerMatchPlayed, String playerGoals, String playerYellowCards, String playerRedCards) {
        this.playerKey = playerKey;
        this.playerName = playerName;
        this.playerNumber = playerNumber;
        this.playerCountry = playerCountry;
        this.playerType = playerType;
        this.playerAge = playerAge;
        this.playerMatchPlayed = playerMatchPlayed;
        this.playerGoals = playerGoals;
        this.playerYellowCards = playerYellowCards;
        this.playerRedCards = playerRedCards;
    }

    public long getPlayerKey() {
        return playerKey;
    }

    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public String getPlayerNumber() {
        return playerNumber;
    }

    public String getPlayerCountry() {
        return playerCountry;
    }

    public String getPlayerType() {
        return playerType;
    }

    public String getPlayerAge() {
        return playerAge;
    }

    public String getPlayerMatchPlayed() {
        return playerMatchPlayed;
    }

    public String getPlayerGoals() {
        return playerGoals;
    }

    public String getPlayerYellowCards() {
        return playerYellowCards;
    }

    public String getPlayerRedCards() {
        return playerRedCards;
    }

    public void setPlayerKey(Integer playerKey) {
        this.playerKey = playerKey;
    }

    public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

    public void setPlayerNumber(String playerNumber) {
        this.playerNumber = playerNumber;
    }

    public void setPlayerCountry(String playerCountry) {
        this.playerCountry = playerCountry;
    }

    public void setPlayerType(String playerType) {
        this.playerType = playerType;
    }

    public void setPlayerAge(String playerAge) {
        this.playerAge = playerAge;
    }

    public void setPlayerMatchPlayed(String playerMatchPlayed) {
        this.playerMatchPlayed = playerMatchPlayed;
    }

    public void setPlayerGoals(String playerGoals) {
        this.playerGoals = playerGoals;
    }

    public void setPlayerYellowCards(String playerYellowCards) {
        this.playerYellowCards = playerYellowCards;
    }

    public void setPlayerRedCards(String playerRedCards) {
        this.playerRedCards = playerRedCards;
    }
}

4. TEAMSMAIN

    package com.example.teams.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TeamsMain {

    @SerializedName("success")
    private Integer success;
    @SerializedName("result")
    private List<Result> result ;
    public TeamsMain(Integer success, List<Result> result) {
        this.success = success;
        this.result = result;
    }



    public Integer getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Integer success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public List<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you fix the code, like share only the important one?

Comment: The one shared is my Model classes, the Json data I want to display and the adapter and mainactivity class. I new to this android and would love any help or advice in this case